# Why can regular polygons be inscribed into a circumference?

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

Why can regular polygons be inscribed into a circumference? I have asked this to myself a lot of times. I have also wondered why all triangles can be inscribed into a circumference but I think that it is not so difficult to see why.

I also have another question. Suppose that you have a circumference of radius $R$ and you draw a chord of length $L$ in some direction. And then draw another circumference with the same radius and draw another chord with same length $L$ but in another direction, is it possible to rotate the second figure or apply some transformation to it, so that it looks like the first figure? It might be a silly question but I'd appreciate any answer or help. Thanks.

Comment: It's because the "center of mass" on a regular polygon is equidistant from all of the polygon's vertices, so that center can serve as the center of a circle with radius equal to that "equidistance".  For the triangle, think about how to prove that any $3$ points in the plane determine a unique circle.

Comment: As to your second question, the answer is yes.  Rotate the second circle until the two chords are parallel.  It's possible that the chord in one circle is above the center, and the chord in the other circle below the center, but then just rotate one of them $180^\circ.$

Comment: You will agree that by rotating the circle, you can make one end point of both chords coincident. Then as the chords have the same length, the other endpoints will also coincide.

Answer (score 4):

Take two consecutive sides of your regular polygon, as $AB$ and $BC$ in the diagram below, and draw their perpendicular bisectors, intersecting at point $O$. The properties of the perpendicular bisector imply $AO\cong BO\cong CO$. It follows that triangles $OAB$ and $OBC$ are isosceles and congruent by SSS, and
$$
\angle OBA\cong\angle OBC\cong{1\over2}\angle ABC
\cong{1\over2}\angle BCD\cong\angle OCB\cong\angle OCD.
$$

Consider now side $CD$, consecutive to $BC$. By SAS triangles $BCO$ and $DCO$ are congruent, hence $DO\cong CO$ and $\angle OCD\cong\angle ODC\cong\angle ODE$. You can go on like that, to show that all vertices have the same distance from $O$.

[image]